# how to move from question to question for a quiz app

Tags: android

Essentially what I will be writing is a quiz type application. Basically there will be a paragraph or so to read, with one or more choices below. There will be several criteria to decide what the next question will be, ie. If it was a hard question and get it wrong, the next is easier, or maybe less choices, etc.

Where would I put the logic to determine what the next question would be? Also, once I have what the next question would be, how do I update both the text part, as well as the new choices?

Answer (score 1):

You generate TextViews on the go, and replace them after storing the result of the previous question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Item Response Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item_response_theory).